# How to use alias in activity diagram of plantUML?

Tags: plantuml

I want to draw a diagram like below.
[image]

And my origin code is :

```
@startuml
start

if (c1) then (YES) 
    :A; 
else (NO)
  if (C2) then (NO)
     :A;
    else (NO)
    :C;
  endif
endif
stop
@enduml
```

It seems that there is no alias syntax in new plantUml syntax. I've found the old syntax is `--> "some activity" as render`.
How can I refer to the same activity?

Comment: What did you try sofar / show some code?  (easily tested with your own plantuml version or with http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000). Did you have a look at http://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta for some examples.

Comment: I've already done what you said before asking question and even more. And I found no answer.

Comment: Don't see a solution either, but wouldn't a reformulation like `if (C1 or C2) then A else C` be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you saw this [experimental feature](https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta#2f8a92e645aba14f) already?

> You can use `label` and `goto` keywords to denote goto processing, with:
>
> - `label <label_name>`
> - `goto <label_name>`

```
@startuml
start

if (c1) then (YES) 
    label sp_lab0
    label A    ' define the label to later reference it with goto
    :A; 
else (NO)
  if (C2) then (NO)
    label sp_lab1
     goto A    ' reference label to goto
    else (NO)
    :C;
  endif
endif

stop
@enduml
```

[image]